# How do I count the number of elements of list from another list in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have been trying to count the number of elements from a list which the elements are also from another list.

`ys` is the original list and `ele` is the list of elements.

So that `count 6 [1,2,3] = 3` because it counts the elements of "`0..5`"

My idea is to implement the `ele` function into the `count` function to get this done, but I have no clue how to do that.

I have tried to insert ele n into "`(filter (== ele n) ys)`"in to code below :

```
count :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
count n ys = length (filter (== n) ys)

ele n = [ n | n <- [0..n-1]]
```

But apparently it doesn't work out and the above code is the code I got so far

Comment: "it doesn't work" should always be followed by an error message.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I'm so sorry I did not mention the error message, it says ` No instance for (Num [Integer]) arising from the literal ‘1’
    ‧ In the expression: 1
      In the second argument of ‘count’, namely ‘[1, 2, 3]’
      In the expression: count 6 [1, 2, 3]` 

That was what I got if i put ele n into filter (== ele n)

Comment: FYI, you don't need the comprehension for `ele n`.  It's the same thing as `ele n = [0..n-1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, you might try this

```
count n ys = length (filter (flip elem (ele n)) ys)
```

Notice that in order to filter a list by `(== ele n)`, you would have to have a list of lists of numbers, because each element in the list will be checked for equality against the list of numbers `ele n`. If you want to check that each element of `ys` is in `ele n`, you should use the [`elem`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:elem) function instead of `==`.

Because `elem` takes the element as its first argument and the list as its second argument, you can use the [`flip`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:flip) function to set up your filter function. `flip` takes a function of two arguments and returns a function that does the same thing but takes its arguments in the opposite order. For example, instead of writing

```
elem 3 [1..5]
```

you can write

```
flip elem [1..5] 3
```

An alternative solution would be to use [`intersect`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:intersect) from Data.List, in which case you wouldn't have to use a filter at all.

```
import Data.List
count n ys = length (intersect ys (ele n))
```

Comment: `flip elem (ele n)` can be written `(\`elem\` (ele n))` which is arguably more readable.